# Thrift generated nodejs that references other thrift generated npm packages

Tags: node.js, thrift

I'm trying to find the best way to reuse common Thrift structures across different NodeJS projects.

I have some common thrift structs like `Date` and `Time`, that exist in an npm packaged module `thrift-common`. I've generated the nodejs files for my `thrift-common` module and deployed them into a local npm repository. I have another thrift service in another project, `clock-service`, that wants to depend on these common structures. I'm using `package.json` to link `clock-service` to `thrift-common`.

The issue I'm having is that generated nodejs thrift files use the require pattern `require('./other-generated-file')` which implies that the entire thrift dependency tree gets generated (or at least moved) into the same directory which kind of defeats the purpose of having an npm package available in the first place.

*Example project structure*

```
/thrift-common/package.json
/thrift-common/thrift/dates.thrift
/thrift-common/gen-node/dates.js
/clock-service/package.json                   <- has dependency on thrift-common
/clock-service/index.js                       <- starts thrift server and implements 
                                                 clock-service.js
/clock-service/thrift/clock-service.thrift    <- includes thrift-common.thrift somehow
/clock-service/node_modules/thrift-common/... <- from npm
/clock-service/gen-node/clock-service.js      <- requires thrift-common.js somehow
```

I'd like a solution that makes reusing thrift files (and their generated node files) as easy as possible.